# How To provide reference to another table from one table by using composite key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, jdbc

Suppose I have one table which has two primary keys(composite key) and I want to provide reference to another table with the help of first table, so what should I do?

Comment: "two primary keys (composite key)" <-- That's actually a SINGLE composite primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>
  <p>CREATE TABLE SUPPLIER (<br/>
  SupplierId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,<br/>
  CompanyName VARCHAR(40),<br/>
  ContactName VARCHAR(40),<br/>
  Phone INT,<br/>
  City VARCHAR(40),<br/>
  Country VARCHAR(40)<br/>
  )</p>
  <p>CREATE TABLE PRODUCT (<br/> 
 ProductId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,<br/>
 ProductName VARCHAR(40),<br/>
 SupplierId FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES SUPPLIER(SupplierId),<br/>
 UnitPrice INT<br/>
)<p>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple :

```
Create Table Test1
    (
    PK1 int not null
    , PK2 int not null
    , Primary Key ( PK1, PK2 )
    )

Create Table Test2
    (
    Id int not null Auto_Increment
    , PK1 int not null
    , PK2 int not null
    , Primary Key ( ID )
    , Constraint FK_Test2
        Foreign Key ( PK1, PK2 )
        References Test1( PK1, PK2 )
    )
```

**PS :** to avoid having **VOTE DOWNS** in here,  you must provide what you tried and what problems you had.

good luck.